# Shop ImageButton to unlock

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, imagebutton

[my shop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uMel.png)

That's imageButton where I'm trying each button unclickable if the coins is not equal to the price, plus a code where it'll deduct if clicked with a toast alert "success"

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple!

First, set `android:clickable="false"` to all Imagebuttons in your layout file.

Then, Use SharedPreferences to save the value of your coins

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("coins", "100");
        editor.apply();
```

And then you can verify if coins is not equal to the price in OnCreate activity method:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    button100 = findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    button150 = findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    button300 = findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    button450 = findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);

    button100.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counterMtd();
        }
    });

    button150.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counterMtd();
        }
    });

    button300.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counterMtd();
        }
    });

    button450.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counterMtd();
        }
    });
}

private void counterMtd(){

    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String coins = preferences.getString("coins", "0");
    int coinsCounter = Integer.parseInt(coins);

    if (coinsCounter >= 100){

        button100.setClickable(true);
        button150.setClickable(false);
        button300.setClickable(false);
        button450.setClickable(false);
    }

    if (coinsCounter >= 150){

        button100.setClickable(true);
        button150.setClickable(true);
        button300.setClickable(false);
        button450.setClickable(false);
    }

    if (coinsCounter >= 300){

        button100.setClickable(true);
        button150.setClickable(true);
        button300.setClickable(true);
        button450.setClickable(false);
    }

    if (coinsCounter >= 450){

        button100.setClickable(true);
        button150.setClickable(true);
        button300.setClickable(true);
        button450.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

Explaining:

- button100 is referring to the button you can buy 100 coins
- button150 is referring to the button you can buy 150 coins
- button300 is referring to the button you can buy 300 coins
- button450 is referring to the button you can buy 450 coins

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks really for your time. Can i add some alert at least like a toast, to at least there is something happening or the color is grey if not clickable

Comment: To set button color gray: button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));

Comment: Thanks, the problem now is when clicked, it is not reducing coins

Comment: I edited the answer, please look at it and tells me if doesn't work.

Comment: after i added the edited code, it is not working now, not clickable nor reducing any coins